# What is the correct way to convert from a javafx ObjectProperty to as scalafx ObjectProperty

Tags: scalafx

Say I have the following code:

```
import scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty
import scalafx.scene.image.Image

def foo(property: ObjectProperty[Image]) = {...}
```

Then somewhere else I have an image view who's imageProperty I want to pass to the function:

```
import scalafx.scene.image.ImageView

val view: ImageView
...
val property = view.image
foo(property) // will not compile
```

This will not compile as the property returned from image is a javafx..Image as opposed to scalafx.

Is it sufficient to do

```
foo(property.asInstanceOf[ObjectProperty[Image]])
```

or is there a better way of converting?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I got it to work was with an explicit call to delegate. Something like the following:

```
import scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty
import scalafx.scene.image.Image

def foo(property: ObjectProperty[jfxsi.Image]) = {
...
  val image: Image
  ...
  property.set(image.delegate) 
}
```